# Add website password in Edge manually

Tags: microsoft-edge

I'm tried to save a password for a web page form in Edge so I don't have to type it every time.

I have save passwords turned on but when I type the credentials and press enter the save password dialog flashes up quickly and I don't have time to access it (been trying a lot!).

The password manager in Edge doesn't seem to allow me to add a new site manually.

Does anyone have a way to do this?

Comment: Can you save the password in a mature browser like chrome or firefox? Some sites won't let you save the password (look at the form source)

Comment: The site I'm accessing only works in Edge and IE. I have same problem with IE but ideally would prefer to use Edge.

Comment: If the site is badly designed and doesn't work in major browsers, all bets are off. But look at the page source, to see if password saving is disabled.

Comment: What about using the Credentials Manager in the control panel

Answer (score 1):

You can use one trick. Go to the login page of your website. enter you're user name and password but don't click login or in your case enter.
A key shape should have come up on the address bar. Click on it and just save the password.